# Both users_signup_test and user_test fail after ActionMailer configuration(based off of Michael Hartl tutorial)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, railstutorial.org

I am trying to make a simple application that just sends an email with a picture of a dog in it to whoever signs up to use as an example for myself for creating mailers in other applications. My user model and integration tests were passing before I added the code for my ActionMailer. I'm not sure what's going on/why they are failing as I have made no changes to the user.rb model or the users_controller.rb file besides adding a private email(which isn't the problem, I've removed the method and reverted the model back to its original state and get the same error messages). If anyone can help me or knows why this could happening that would be great!

Edit: Here is my bitbucket repository: https://bitbucket.org/corourke24/daves-double-down-dogs

The error messages that I'm getting are as follows:

```
Failure:
UsersSignupTest#test_valid_signup_info [/home/ubuntu/workspace/test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:17]:
"User.count" didn't change by 1.
Expected: 4
  Actual: 3


bin/rails test test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:15

...F

Failure:
UserTest#test_email_validation_should_accept_valid_email_addresses [/home/ubuntu/workspace/test/models/user_test.rb:39]:
Expected false to be truthy.


bin/rails test test/models/user_test.rb:34

F

Failure:
UserTest#test_user_should_have_valid_email [/home/ubuntu/workspace/test/models/user_test.rb:14]:
Expected false to be truthy.


bin/rails test test/models/user_test.rb:13

F

Failure:
UserTest#test_user_should_be_valid [/home/ubuntu/workspace/test/models/user_test.rb:10]:
Expected false to be truthy.


bin/rails test test/models/user_test.rb:9
```

Here is my user.rb model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    before_save :email_downcase
    EMAIL_REGEXP =  /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: EMAIL_REGEXP },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

    private

        def email_downcase
            self.email = email.downcase
        end

end
```

Here is my users_controller.rb file:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      UserMailer.account_activation(@user).deliver_now
      redirect_to root_path
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to Dave's Double Down Dogs!"
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email)
    end
end
```

Here is my application_cpontroller.rb file:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

Here is my users.yml file:

```
christian:
  email: christian@example.com

example:
  email: user@example.com

user:
  email: user1@example.com
```

Here is my seeds.rb file:

```
User.create!(email: "example@railstutorial.org")
```

Here is my user_test.rb file:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def setup
    @user = User.new(email: "user@example.com")
  end

  test "user should be valid" do
    assert @user.valid?
  end

  test "user should have valid email" do
    assert @user.valid?  
  end

  test "emails hould be valid" do
    @user.email = "   "
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "email should not be too long" do
    @user.email = 'i' * 244 + '@example.com'
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "email addresses should be unique" do
    dup_user = @user.dup
    dup_user.email = @user.email.upcase
    @user.save
    assert_not dup_user.valid?
  end

  test "email validation should accept valid email addresses" do
    valid_addresses = %w[user@example.com USER@foo.COM A_US-ER@foo.bar.org
                     first.last@foo.jp alice+bob@baz.cn]
    valid_addresses.each do |i|
      @user.email = i
      assert @user.valid?
    end
  end

  test "email validation should reject invalid email addresses" do
    invalid_addresses = %w[user@example,com user_at_foo.org user.name@example.
                       foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
    invalid_addresses.each do |i|
      @user.email = i
      assert_not @user.valid?
    end
  end

  test "email addresses should be saved in lowercase" do
    multi_case_email = "Foo@ExAMPle.CoM"
    @user.email = multi_case_email
    @user.save
    assert_equal multi_case_email.downcase, @user.reload.email
  end

end
```

Here is my users_signup_test.rb file:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersSignupTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "invalid signup info" do
    get signup_path
    assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
      post signup_path, params: { user: { email: "" } }
    end
    assert_template 'users/new'
    assert_select 'div#error_explanation'
    assert_select 'div.field_with_errors'
  end

  test "valid signup info" do
    get signup_path
    assert_difference 'User.count', 1 do
      post signup_path, params: { user: { email: "user@example.com" } }
    end
    assert_redirected_to root_path
    flash[:success] 
  end

end
```

Edit: after realizing that the problem may be caused by duplicate email addressed being made by my

```
def setup
    @user = User.new(email: "user@example.com")
end
```

method in my user_test.rb interacting with my users.yml file I have changed my users.yml file to be:

```
christian:
  email: christian@example.gov

example:
  email: user@example.gov

user:
  email: userx@example.gov
```

However, the error messages I get now are as follows:

```
.E

Error:
UsersSignupTest#test_valid_signup_info:
NameError: uninitialized constant UsersController::UserMailer
    app/controllers/users_controller.rb:14:in `create'
    test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UsersSignupTest>'
    test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:17:in `block in <class:UsersSignupTest>'


bin/rails test test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last error was caused by UserMailer in the users_controller, changing it to DogMailer fixed the error